# Адаптив слайдера, уходящего в правую границу экрана

Tags: css, slider

Помогите сделать адаптив слайдера как на схеме:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
чтобы при уменьшении ширины экрана полупрозрачные зеленые блоки 4 и 5 обрезались справа границей окна, а меню и блоки 1,2 и 3 не меняли своих размеров и оставались стоять ровно относительно центра страницы, красных пунктирных полосок и баннера, который тоже не изменяется по ширине.

Блоков в слайдере будет больше 5

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 40% 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "banner banner" "menu slider";
}

.banner {
  grid-area: banner;
  background-color: #D7D7D9;
}

.menu {
  grid-area: menu;
  background-color: #9FA1A6;
}

.slider {
  grid-area: slider;
  background-color: #F0F0F2;
  
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.slide {
  min-width: calc(100% / 5 - 1rem);
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  background-color: #404040;
  
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 5rem;
  color: white;
  
  transition: 0.5s;
}

@media screen and  (max-width : 768px) {
  .slide {
    min-width: calc(100% / 3 - 1rem);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"></div>
<div class="menu"></div>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">2</div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
  <div class="slide">4</div>
  <div class="slide">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не так.

Мне нужно, чтобы как на моей схеме: 4, 5 блоки полностью или частично скрывались в зависимости от ширины экрана. А меню и блоки 1,2,3  не меняли своей ширины и позиции относительно верхнего баннера, ширина которого тоже не меняется